# What can I do if I forget my passcode to my device (Samsung Galaxy Tab E(2017))?

Tags: samsung, settings, security

My brother changed the passcode on his device and it glitched out or something and he has no access to it at all, what can he do?

Comment: He need to perform a factory reset. This will delete everything stored in the device.

Comment: There has to be something other than that, like using a lock screen remover or something.

Comment: And can you please answer in the answer question section.

Comment: There is no such thing called a lock screen remover.

Comment: Yes there is! there is dr.fone, we already tried it but we failed, I will try it again, there is a slightly different method we didn't try.

Comment: How do you use it? Lock removers works only when USB debugging is on. Otherwise I can't see a way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform a factory reset that will clear everything stored in the phone memory, unfortunately.

If you previously enabled USB Debugging in the Developer Options, there is a way to remove or reset the lock screen. No data is lost here.

Edit:

On some Samsung device, you can reset the lock code with AT commands when the device on Download mode (Never tried myself though). Some paid softwares can do the job just on one click. **z3x**, **Miracle Box**, etc

Comment: How do you do the second method though. HUUH???

Comment: And no his USB debugging is off.

Comment: There is no way to enable USB debugging on a locked device.

Comment: 1. not being rude, but I'm not dumb, I have some device and technology experience.

Comment: What do I have to understand here?

Answer (score 0):

If the phone's rooted you can try adb. But for Adb you should need the adb debugging option enabled on the phone. write those commands in adb shell of your pc.

adb devices 
adb shell 
cd data/system 
su rm *.key

OR On TWRP Mount the system,use file manager,navigate to data/system remove all files ending with .key

Done.You got your phone unlocked.

Comment: wat? I hev no clu to wat u just said...

Comment: and yes, i is good at english and spellsing

Comment: I mean Unlocking Your phone using "Recovery".Twrp Is a custom recovery for phones.which can help you a lot.

Comment: I did not catch anything u just said

Comment: @smartbot Thought you had some devices and tech experience...